# Rounding to one decimal place SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using the expression below, can someone please advise how I can get it to round to 1 decimal place please?

```
 =Round(Count(Fields!FieldName.Value)) / 8562 *100 & "%"
```

This is the output

```
     49.532819434711516000934361130%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FormatPercent instead. This should work for you.

```
=FormatPercent(Count(Fields!FieldName.Value) / 8562 *100,1)
```